# "ICMP Port Unreachable" - Unable to connect to HIVE db(using KERBEROS) through JDBC

Tags: jdbc, hive, kerberos

I am trying to access HIVE db from my application through JDBC. I am facing some connection issues with it. 
I tried a lot of things here like trying TCP etc but still unsuccessful.

```
public class HiveJDBC {
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  /**
 * @param args
 * @throws SQLException
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
      try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.debug","true");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm","FDLDEV.COM");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","krb5.conf");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc","10.230.137.236");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");

          try{
              LOG.info("Starting:");
              org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
              conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
              UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
              UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("122*121@ABC.COM", "122*121.keytab");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://ip-12-***-156-227.ec2.internal:2999,ip-10-***-123-123.ec2.internal:1299,ip-10-230-137-16.ec2.internal:1299/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2-llap0;principal=123@ABC.COM");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
```

Krb5.conf:

```
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 default_realm = ABC.COM
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 dns_lookup_kdc = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true

[realms]    
FDLDEV.COM = {
   kdc = 10.***.***.236
   admin_server = 10.***.***.236
}

[domain_realm]
.abc.com = ABC.COM
 abc.com = ABC.COM
```

Output :

```
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: ICMP Port Unreachable
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:808) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:952) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.5.jar!/:?]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    ... 83 more
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: java.net.PortUnreachableException: ICMP Port Unreachable
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:143) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:812) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.security.krb5.internal.UDPClient.receive(NetClient.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(KdcComm.java:404) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm$KdcCommunication.run(KdcComm.java:364) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.sendIfPossible(KdcComm.java:253) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:229) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:200) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:316) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:776) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)  ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
2019-08-07T17:27:26.35-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:952) ~[hadoop-common-2.6.5.jar!/:?]
```

What am i missing here ? I spent a lot of time trying to troubleshoot but no luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Basically, Kerberos does not work with IP addresses but with **canonical DNS names** and no ambiguity in the name/IP & IP/name lookups. Maybe the security checks are relaxed in your setup but nonetheless, using IPs probably won't work at some point.

Comment: Kerberos uses UDP by default, as you can see. And UDP is blocked by most firewalls by default. And the Java implementation of Kerberos has a default time-out of 30s plus 3 retries, which exceeds any reasonable Hadoop/Jetty timeout in your client. That's why Cloudera recommends to set explicitly the Java time-out to `3s` in `krb5.conf`

Comment: BTW did you try a simple `kinit` from these machines, to make sure the C implementation of Kerberos worked with your current firewall settings, client `krb5.conf` settings, and KDC settings? Did you try a plain Netcat connection attempt to the KDC on port 88, both UDP and TCP?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem... It is because the code does not load all your conf files. So some of them trys to connect with kerberos but kerberos refuse it so you got ICMP port unreachable.

In short, check out your conf files. The paths are wrong